# simple c++ input function

Tags: c++, function, input, user-input

i am new to c++ from other languages, and looking at examples this code looked like it should work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
          string input = "";
          cout << "in: ";
          getline(cin, input);
          input_recv(input);
}

input_recv(input)
{
                 if (input == "hello"){
                    cout << "derp" << endl;
                    }
}
```

it will not let me use the function input_recv. it gives me several errors in my IDE. one being `input_recv' undeclared (first use this function). basically what i am trying to do for this is make it respond to input using a function.

EDIT:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void input_recv(string);
int main()
{
    while (1 == 1){
          string input = "";
          cout << "in: ";
          getline(cin, input);
          input_recv(input);
          cin.get();
    }
}

void input_recv(string input){
                 if (input == "hello"){
                    cout << "derp" << endl;
                    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: your main function should be declared as int main(void) and the last line should always be a return 0;

Comment: your input_recv function needs a return type.  add void in front of the function declaration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ requires the function to be declared before it's used, so if you move the input_recv definition above the main function, it will work. Otherwise, you can leave the program the way it is and add a forward declaration above main like this:

```
void input_recv(string);
int main()
{
...
}

void input_recv(string input)
{
...
}
```

Edit:
There are a few other errors here as well as other comments pointed out. One, functions should have a return type and parameter types specified. Also, before using the string type, you need to 
`#include <string>`.

Comment: aha. coming from python declaring functions is something completely new to me

Comment: @g-makulik except for the fact that his first answer only took into account 1 of the compilation errors in the posted code :-P

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void input_recv(string);
int main()
{
    while (1 == 1){
          string input = "";
          cout << "in: ";
          getline(cin, input);
          input_recv(input);
          cin.get();
    }
}

void input_recv(string input){
                 if (input == "hello"){
                    cout << "derp" << endl;
                    }
}`

Comment: i have found that cin.get(); works more for what i want then return 0;

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function first, and use a correct function prototype, here there is not type for input, no return type ... Example below,

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 void input_recv(const std::string& input);

int main()
{
     std::string input = "";
     std::cout << "in: ";
     std::getline(std::cin, input);
     input_recv(input);

     return 0;
}

void input_recv(const std::string& input)
{
  if (input == "hello"){
     cout << "derp" << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a strongly-typed language.  You **must** declare your variables and your functions with explicit types:

```
// forward declare your function
void input_recv(std::string input);
// alternatively
void input_recv_better(const std::string& input);

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cout << "In:  ";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    input_recv(input);
    input_recv_better(input);
    return 0;
}

void input_recv(std::string input)
{
    if (input == "hello")
    {
        std::cout << "derp" << std::endl;
    }
}

void input_recv_better(const std::string& input)
{
    if (input == "hello")
    {
        std::cout << "derp!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things definitely wrong with this snippet, I will correct them all so you can observe the difference:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void input_recv(string input);

int main()
{
      string input = "";
      cout << "in: ";
      getline(cin, input);
      input_recv(input);
}

void input_recv(string input)
{
    if (input == "hello"){
        cout << "derp" << endl;
    }
}
```

I have added return types to your functions, data types to your parameters, and a forward declaration of the **input_recv** function so that the main function knows it exists.

You will definitely want to pick up a book like C++ Primer (the latest edition revised for the C++11 standard) before learning bad practice by trying to forgo some sort of standard training.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void input_recv(string input)
{
                 if (input == "hello"){
                    cout << "derp" << endl;
                    }
}

int main()
{
  string input = "";
  cout << "in: ";
  getline(cin, input);
  input_recv(input);

   return 0;
}
```